# how to insert valued variable to $insertSQL/sprintf

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$ma_nv1 = $_GET['catID'];
echo $ma_nv;

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tlb_quanhegiadinh (ma_nhan_vien, ten_nguoi_than, nam_sinh, moi_quan_he, nghe_nghiep, dia_chi, dtll, ghi_chu) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['ma_nv2'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['ten_nguoi_than'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['nam_sinh'], "int"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['moi_quan_he'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['nghe_nghiep'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['dia_chi'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['dtll'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['ghi_chu'], "text"));
?>
```

$ma_nv1 = $_GET['catID'];

I wanna replace **$ma_nv1** into **GetSQLValueString($_POST['ma_nv2'], "text")** How can I?

Comment: wat u want to say????????????

Comment: $ma_nv1 = $_GET['catID'];
I wanna replace **$ma_nv1** into **GetSQLValueString($_POST['ma_nv2'], "text")**
How can I?

Comment: do u want to store value of `$ma_nv1` into `$_POST['ma_nv2']`?

Comment: yeap, this is what i wanna say.

Answer (score 0):

As per I asked in comments.

Do it like

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['ma_nv2'], $ma_nv1);
```

This will store the value of `$ma_nv1` into `$_POST['ma_nv2']`